# How to flatten a list without recursion ocaml?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml, fold, flatten

How would I flatten a list of lists of integers into a single list of integers in ocaml?  The function would work as shown below.

```
[[1;2];[3;4;5];[];[6]] -> [1;2;3;4;5;6]
```

As this is homework, it must be done using only fold_left or fold_right, and cannot use the '@' operator, and cannot use recursion.  I get that the accumulator is going to be the members of the new list, but I have no clue how to actually move the elements of the original list to the accumulator.  Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some hints:

a. Moving a value to the accumulator is not difficult. If your value is `x` and your accumulator is `a`, you can just write `x :: a`.

b. You mostly need to process all the inner values in a consistent order. That's what folds are for.

c. A fold is for processing the elements of a list. But you have a list of lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
List.fold_left (fun liRes la -> 
  List.fold_right ( fun iRes la ->
    iRes::la    
  ) liRes la
) [] [[1;2];[3;4;5];[];[6]]
```

result :

```
- : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6]
```

other form :

```
let (@) =
  List.fold_right ( fun iRes la ->
    iRes::la
  );;

 List.fold_left (fun liRes la -> 
   liRes @ la
 ) [] [[1;2];[3;4;5];[];[6]];;
```

You can try :

```
# []@[1;2];;
- : int list = [1; 2]
# (@) [1;2] [3;4];;
- : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4]
```

Comment: (I'm not sure it's helpful in the big picture to give code for somebody's homework problem.)